# Answer endpoint request with a 406 and then call another method

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I'm having the following dilemma: I have an endpoint in which I have to check have enough money on its bank account to buy a steam code, If he/she has I need to answer the endpoint with an 406 (Accepted) and then call the method to make buy the steam code.

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> steamRecharge(@RequestBody RequestDTO request) throws Exception {
        SteamRechargeService.checkIfClientHasEnoughMoneyOnAccount(request);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Client has enough money", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        SteamRechargeService.rechargeSteamAccount(request);
}
```

I know that this way won't work. If I was coding in JavaScript I would make this method async and then await for `checkIfClientHasEnoughMoneyOnAccount(request);` then asynchronously call the method `SteamRechargeService.rechargeSteamAccount(request);` then return the http response.

Is there a way to do this in Java?

Comment: Check this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async. You can delegate `rechargeSteamAccount` to be invoked as async and do not wait for the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As centrumek sugested I came up with this answer. I created a @Configuration class that had @EnableAsync. The Controller came up something like that:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> steamRecharge(@RequestBody RequestDTO request) throws Exception {
    SteamRechargeService.checkIfClientHasEnoughMoneyOnAccount(request);
    SteamRechargeService.rechargeSteamAccount(request);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Client has enough money", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
```

And the method 'rechargeSteamAccount' has an @async annotation on it.

```
@async
public void rechargeSteamAccount(RequestDTO request){
...
}
```

This works, now I'm sending the HttpStatus and I don't need to wait for 'rechargeSteamAccount' end it's process.